# fill form problem in JavaScript in console chrome

Tags: javascript, forms

I put the following code on a certain site to fill the form, but the form is not filled in real form and only a text that is deleted by clicking is placed on the appearance of the form. What is the reason for this?

this is the form field I'm trying to fill:

[image]

```
<input aria-invalid="false" id="captchaText" name="captchaText" type="text" maxlength="5" class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall muirtl-1o6z5ng" value="">
```

i tried:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="captchaText"]').value = 'abcde';
```

Comment: there are surely obvious mistakes in your js statement that should look like `document.querySelector('input[name="captchaText"]').value = 'abcde';` ... other than that is hard to understand what you meant in your question

Comment: after the edit there's still a mistake.. the closing square bracket is out of place

Comment: I fixed it but my problem is not solved

Comment: Why don't you select element by ID? Name does not need to be unique. `document.getElementById('captchaText').value = 'abcde';`

Comment: I agree using `getElementById` might be more appropriate.. anyway as pointed out you didn't fix that.. and it was enough to copy and paste actually.. [edit..] now that it's correct and there's no reason for it to behave oddly, can you be more clear on what's going wrong? because there are no clear elements to understand the problem

Comment: t tried this:document.getElementById('captchaText').value = 'abcde';

Comment: But the problem was not solved

Comment: and what's the exact issue? did the element exist when you ran `document.getElementById('captchaText')`? are you evaluating that code in the js console open from the loaded page containing that element?

Comment: How to send a photo here is really difficult to explain the problem

Comment: when you edit the question you have the chance to add a picture .. you'll find the corresponding button on the editor toolbar

Comment: Please send me a message on Telegram and send me a picture of my problem. My ID is saeedysss

Comment: please stick to StackOverflow.. it's not hard.. q/a are expected to be handled here in their full lifecycle. If you still can't figure out how to fulfill the trivial task of adding a picture in your question, you may find further info if you try searching here in the help. As a further resort, try here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post (old question indeed but the point is the same)

Comment: It won't let me add a photo, it says you have to ask ten questions to be able to

Comment: I don't think the 10 question thing about adding photos/screenshots is true. I have only asked 5 questions and have no issue adding them! I think you mean 10 rep. Either way, the image you've linked to is inaccessible (at least to me) due to misconfigured/insecure SSL/TLS configuration.

Comment: The photo was added in the link

Comment: that's a captcha and you didn't mention it (despite maybe clear from the html you shared before) ... plus the input text value is actually filled correctly since `abcde` is visible. The placeholder you are seeing overlapping is probably a third element maybe imposed via ::after/::before. But any issue arising go further than anything asked in the question. Plus to be fair a captcha is expected to be filled by a human

Comment: as a further exercise you may just try to trigger the events `click` and `blur` before and after changing the field value. something like: `inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click')); /*change its value here*/ inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));`

Comment: I executed the following code for the username part of the site, but the same problem as before is still there and the form was not filled and it has a ghost state and it is deleted from the page by clicking anywhere.
userName.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
userName.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
document.getElementById('userName').value = '123456';